# UICollectionView reloadSections (possibly?) creates memory leak

Tags: uicollectionview, uikit

I am using `reloadSections(...)` on my `UICollectionView` in order to update supplementaryViews (section header views). This works, but when I look at the memory graph I see that I now have twice as many cells in memory. Everything seems to be duplicated.

I noticed this because I saw a new cell being initialized, but `deinit` was never called. So I inspected with the `Debug Memory Graph` function.

Is this a bug in my code or is this simply some optimisation UIKit has?

I should perhaps add I have each cell type just once or twice, so there are many cell types in my collection view.